# Messages App acts like its disembodied

Tags: messages, data-synchronization

I use my iPhone and the app Messages interchangeably for sending and receiving messages. They are both connected to my apple account and for a long time they worked in sync. However, recently Messages has begun to act particularly. For instance, it views all messages in the thread that have not been checked since the last time the app was open as unread (as oppose to being marked read, when I read them on my phone.) This includes my own messages that I have sent out. Also, when  I try to send a message from the app, it immediately returns not delivered.

Any ideas?

This is only on the Mac app, my iPhone still works fine.
I'm using 10.13.2 High Sierra and iOS 10.3.3

Edit: Restarted my computer (not the first time I've tried this since the problem stated), but for some reason this randomly fixed it. I don't know why. If anyone has any insight into why restarting my computer this time work, I'd be happy to hear.

Comment: Try signing out and signing in again! - From the Messages app, open the Preferences window, select your iCloud account and click the Sign Out button. Then sign in again afterwards.

Comment: Didn't fix it. Its weird because it does acknowledge my account (my contacts are correct, all the previous messages  are present)